# Is it possible to configure FTP server to prevent from file overwriting?

Tags: ftp

I have experience only with ProFTPd.

I understand that I need disallow: **APPE DELE RNFR RNTO** command but seems that **STOR** command override existing files.

Is it possible to configure FTP server to prevent from file overwriting? Which ftp servers allow this?

Answer (score 1):

For `proftpd` you can just use [directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_AllowOverwrite.html):

```
AllowOverwrite off
```

Comment: How it will work? I see, upload file with the same name will be impossible. but will be possible delete file, upload it again with the same name? rename file? and optionally resume upload for this file or possible resume when file has been created recently?